# json_encode UTF-8 in PHP 5.3.3

Tags: php, json

Trying to save data with specials characters using json_encode.

Code sample:

```
$a = array("Name" => "SáENZ PEñA");
echo "Normal : ",  json_encode($a), "<br>";
echo "Unicode : ", json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), "<br>";
```

**JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE** solve the issue with php 5.6

```
Normal : {"Name":"S\u00e1ENZ PE\u00f1A"}
Unicode : {"Name":"SáENZ PEñA"}
```

but unfortunelly i have php 5.3 :

```
Normal : {"Name":"S\u00e1ENZ PE\u00f1A"}
Unicode : 
Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /var/www/.../TEST.php on line 4
```

Any solution that works with php 5.3 ?

Comment: why you are passing already encoded data to re-encode again? pass array

Comment: To save data in a json file with fwrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`, you could probably unescape the JSON yourself after it's been encoded:

- Compatible with \ (escaped backslashes itself)
- Compatible with JSON_HEX_* flags

  `function raw_json_encode($input, $flags = 0) {
      $fails = implode('|', array_filter(array(
          '\\\\',
          $flags & JSON_HEX_TAG ? 'u003[CE]' : '',
          $flags & JSON_HEX_AMP ? 'u0026' : '',
          $flags & JSON_HEX_APOS ? 'u0027' : '',
          $flags & JSON_HEX_QUOT ? 'u0022' : '',
      )));
      $pattern = "/\\\\(?:(?:$fails)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|u([0-9a-fA-F]{4}))/";
      $callback = function ($m) {
          return html_entity_decode("&#x$m[1];", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
      };
      return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, json_encode($input, $flags));
  }`

**Example**

```
<?php

function raw_json_encode($input, $flags = 0) {
    $fails = implode('|', array_filter(array(
        '\\\\',
        $flags & JSON_HEX_TAG ? 'u003[CE]' : '',
        $flags & JSON_HEX_AMP ? 'u0026' : '',
        $flags & JSON_HEX_APOS ? 'u0027' : '',
        $flags & JSON_HEX_QUOT ? 'u0022' : '',
    )));
    $pattern = "/\\\\(?:(?:$fails)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|u([0-9a-fA-F]{4}))/";
    $callback = function ($m) {
        return html_entity_decode("&#x$m[1];", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    };
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, json_encode($input, $flags));
}

$json = array(
    'Sample' => array(
        'specialchars' => '<x>& \' "</x>',
        'backslashes' => '\\u0020',
        'context' => 'جمهوری اسلامی ایران',
    )
);

echo raw_json_encode($json, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT);

/* 
{"Sample":{"specialchars":"\u003Cx\u003E\u0026 \u0027 \u0022\u003C\/x\u003E","backslashes":"\\u0020","context":"جمهوری اسلامی ایران"}}
*/
```